# create JSON from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

How can I create a javascript JSON (?) object based on two input fields per row, with 48 rows?

I have this:

```
<div><input name = "name" /></div> <div><input name = "rating" /></div>
<div><input name = "name" /></div> <div><input name = "rating" /></div>
<div><input name = "name" /></div> <div><input name = "rating" /></div>
...
...
```

I then want to sort the object on rating (desc). Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my way:

1. Put all row to 1 form with unique name per input.
2. Get form data via jquery.
3. Use my `formObj2Json()` function convert form data to json with key per item is input unique name.

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#grap', function(){
  var formData = $('#anph').serializeArray(),
      rs = formObj2Json(formData);

  $('#rs').html(JSON.stringify(rs, undefined, 2));
});


})


function formObj2Json(formArray) { //serialize data function
  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0, len = formArray.length; i < len; i++)
    returnArray[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
  return returnArray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Knockout 1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>

<body>
  <button id="grap">grap</button>
   <form id="anph">

  <div class="group"><input name="name1" /><input name="rating1" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name2" /><input name="rating2" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name3" /><input name="rating3" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name4" /><input name="rating4" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name5" /><input name="rating5" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name6" /><input name="rating6" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name7" /><input name="rating7" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name8" /><input name="rating8" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name9" /><input name="rating9" /></div>
<div class="group"><input name="name10" /><input name="rating10" /></div>
</form>

<pre id="rs"></pre>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this help?

```js
var pl=[['Jack',1],['Jill',2],['Lucy',3],['Marc',4],['John',5],['Eva',6],['Anne',7],['Ben',8]];

divs=$('div[id^=NAME]');
pl.forEach(function(v,i){divs[i].innerHTML=v[0]+' (rank: '+v[1]+')';})
```

```css
div {display: inline-block; width:120px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NAME-1"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-2"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-3"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-4"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-5"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-6"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-7"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-8"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-9"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-10"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-11"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-12"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-13"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-14"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-15"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-16"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-17"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-18"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-19"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-20"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-21"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-22"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-23"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-24"></div><br/>
<div id="NAME-25"></div> vs. <div id="NAME-26"></div>
```

`pl` is your sorted array of arrays and `divs` is a jquery object containing your target divs you want to put the values in. Maybe they can all be found in an enclosing container? In that case you can use a different selector for finding them.

**Edit: (answer to edited question)**

To collect the data from your input fields you could do the following:

```js
$(function(){
 var i,str='';
 for (var i=1;i<11;i++) 
   str+='<input type="text" name="n'+i+'" placeholder="Name '+i+'"/> '
       +'<input type="text" name="r'+i+'" placeholder="Rating '+i+'"/><br/>';
 $('#frm1').prepend(str);
 $('#go').click(go);
})
function go(){
 var name, jsn=$.makeArray($('input','#frm1').map(function(i,o){
    var v=$(o).val(); if (i%2 && v>0) return [[name,v]]; else name=v;}));
 jsn.sort(function(a,b){ return a[1]-b[1];});
 $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(jsn));
 return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm1"><button id="go">go</button></form>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Well, in case "it does *not* help", why not just tell me? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var players = [{ name: "Paul", rank: 1}, {name: "Michael", rank: 2}];

    $.each(players, function(key, value){ 
      $("#containerofPlayers").append('<div id="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + ' is ranked ' + value.rank + '</div>');
    });
  });
</script>
```

What's happening is that you have an **array of objects**. You loop through each object within the array to get its data. You then create and append a new div with the values to the `<div id="containerofPlayers"></div>` element.

Hope this helps.

Edit: If you don't want to create the `<div>` elements in jQuery but simply assign the text, you could do this instead:

```
$('#'+value.name).text(value.name + " is ranked " + value.rank);
```

---

## Edited answer:

Since you've changed your original question,

```
<div><input name="name" /></div> <div><input name = "rating" /></div>
```

do something more like ↓

```html
<div id="players">
    <div class="player">
        <label>Name: </label><input class="playerName" type="text"/>
        <label>Rank: </label><input class="playerRank" type="number"/>
    </div>
    <div class="player">
        <label>Name: </label><input class="playerName" type="text"/>
        <label>Rank: </label><input class="playerRank" type="number"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  var players = []; //create an Array
  $("#players .player").each(function(i, obj){
    var playerName = $(this).children('.playerName').val();
    var playerRank = $(this).children('.playerRank').val();
    $(this).push({"name": playerName, "rank": playerRank}); // this will give you an array of objects like in my previous answer, then you can use that data to display it.
  });

  players.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return (a.rank - b.rank) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name); 
  });

  $.each(players, function(index, value){
      $("#result").append('<div id="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + ' is ranked ' + value.rank + '</div>');
  })
});
```

Comment: Note that the Rating input field simplifies things. No more code look up voodoo. Simpler way is cleaner and better, imho.

Comment: I changed the format of the listing. Sensible straightforward code is my goal.  I added name = "name" and name = "rating" to the two relevant input fields. Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: I'm getting in deeper and deeper. I will re-edit the question.

Comment: @verlager I've edited my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: This looks very promising. But how do I call this code? I need a button to generate the listing code of the array. How can I do that?

Comment: You should look at the basics of jQuery but, basically this will be called on page load. You need to create an element like `<div id="generator">Generate</div>`, then you do like this


     $(function() {
        $('#generator').on('click',function(){
            var players = []; //create an Array
            ...
        })
     });

Comment: @verlager did this fix it?